# Why there is no userID? it is undefined

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

Hello my friends i am trying to save data to firebase while using userID However i could not make it ! Please can anyone help me ?

```
class ImportScreen extends Component {
   
    

    writeuserdata( name, surname, age, userId) {
        firebase.database().ref('Users/' + userId).set({
            name,
            surname,
            age
        }).then((data) => {
            console.log('data', data)
        }).catch ((error) => {
            console.log('eror',error)
        })
    }



    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', backgroundColor: 'white' }}>

                <TextInput
                    
                    placeholder="Enter a name"
                    onChangeText={(name) => this.setState({ name })}
                  
                />

                <TextInput
                 
                    placeholder="Enter a surname"
                    onChangeText={(surname) => this.setState({ surname })}
                    
                />

                <TextInput
            
                    placeholder="Enter age"
                    onChangeText={(age) => this.setState({ age })}
                    
                />

                <Button
                    title="Save"
                    onPress={() => this.writeuserdata(this.state.name, this.state.surname, this.state.age)} />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcfvF.png)

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `writeuserdata` with:

```
this.writeuserdata(this.state.name, this.state.surname, this.state.age)}
```

Since `writeuserdata` expects 4 parameters, and you're only passing 3, the 4th argument is going to be `undefined`.

If you want to also pass the UID of the current Firebase Authentication user, that'd be something like:

```
this.writeuserdata(this.state.name, this.state.surname, this.state.age, firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)}
```